# Opening times of the border between Greece and Albania

Tags: borders, greece, albania

We are a family from Bulgaria, who are traveling by car from Greece to Albania. We would like to know what's working time on the Konispol/Sagiada border between Greece and Albania?

Answer (score 3):

The [duty free shop](http://www.dutyfreeshops.gr/gr/katastimata/?cat=4) at the Greek side of the border is open 7am - 9pm, so these hours should be a safe bet for the border control to be open as well.

Contact details (page in Greek) of the border control offices [here](https://portal.gsis.gr/portal/page/portal/ICISnet/authority/customsOffices?article=3979657&p_topic=customs&region=07).

Lastly, I found a [photo](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-KClIHuMXhGU/V6q1N2OLooI/AAAAAAABOq8/xF26cHirBfYvzo2RbwgO6mNlH6mCwyWMACLcB/s1600/%25CE%25A4%25CE%25B5%25CE%25BB%25CF%2589%25CE%25BD%25CE%25B5%25CE%25AF%25CE%25BF%25CF%2585%2B%25CE%259C%25CE%25B1%25CF%2585%25CF%2581%25CE%25BF%25CE%25BC%25CE%25B1%25CF%2584%25CE%25AF%25CE%25BF%25CF%2585.jpg) of the border.